# Why is a unique required CharField not giving a IntegrityError when empty?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

With the following model:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
```

This test fails:

```
def test_no_name_error(self):
    '''Ensure an Error is raised when creating a client with no name
    '''
    with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
        client = Client.objects.create()
```

The test fails with:

```
FAIL: test_no_name_error (projects.tests.test_models.ClientModelTests)
Ensure an Error is raised when creating a client with no name
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    client = Client.objects.create()
AssertionError: IntegrityError not raised
```

I am using `mysql`

Comment: You need to add 2. Otherwise it will still be unique. Although it should through a Null exception.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid - the first entry uses the default `''`, not `None`. If a field has `null=True, unique=True` you can have multiple rows with value `null`, because `null != null` in SQL.

Comment: @Alasdair it only uses the default if `blank=True` otherwise it throws an exception.

Comment: @Alasdair and `null` isn't set to `True` in this case.

Comment: That's my point - null isn't set to `True`, so you shouldn't get a 'Null exception'. Try running the code above, the created client will have `name=''`, regardless of the setting of blank

Comment: @Alasdair sorry, I didn't mean 'null exception' I meant that it would complain that it was null. And you are right, of course. Apologies and thanks =)